# Snowflake timestamp conversion issue

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am facing an issue with snowflake when converting a string to timestamp. Here is an example....

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('18090322033010','DDMMYYHH24MISS')
```

can anyone help me to convert this? the output should be 2003-09-18 22:03:3010

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Why are you expecting 3010 to be seconds?

Try this:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('180903220330','DDMMYYHH24MISS');
```

OR this:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('18090322033010','DDMMYYHH24MISSFF');
```